# Image slider play/pause works fine with buttons but not on hover

Tags: jquery

Been messing around with an image slider today that I want to pause when the cursor is on the current image which sort of works but it goes back to the first image instead of keeping its position. It works fine when I use buttons but hover has issues.

JSFiddle with buttons: https://jsfiddle.net/w16c7os0/1/

JSFiddle with hover: https://jsfiddle.net/w16c7os0/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

<style>
    section {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    div {
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }

    #box_1 { left: -150%; }
    #box_2 { left: 50%; }
    #box_3 { left: 150%; }
</style>

<section>
    <div id="box_1" style="background-color: aqua;"><input value="A"></div>
    <div id="box_2" style="background-color: blue;"><input value="B"></div>
    <div id="box_3" style="background-color: crimson;"><input value="C"></div>
</section>

<input id="btnPlay" type="button" value="Play">
<input id="btnPause" type="button" value="Pause">
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var item_1 = $('#box_1');
    var item_2 = $('#box_2');
    var item_3 = $('#box_3');

    var $x;
    var hero_slideshow;
    var currSlide = $('section div:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
    var currSlideNum = currSlide.substr('4', '4');
    var status = 0;



    $('#btnPlay').click(function() { $x = 2; start(); });

    $('#btnPause').click(function() { pause(); });

    $x = 2;
    start();
    $('#'+currSlide).mouseenter(function() { pause(); });
    $('#'+currSlide).mouseleave(function() { $x = 2; start(); });



    function start() {
        if(status == 2) {
            status = 3;
            currSlideNum = currSlide.substr('4', '4');
            $x = currSlideNum;
        } else {
            status = 1;
        };

        hero_slideshow = setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
    };

    function pause() {
        status = 2;
        clearInterval(hero_slideshow);
    };

    function changeImage() {
        if($x > 2) {
            $('section div:nth-child('+$x+')').animate({ left: '-150%' }, 500);
            $x = 1;
            $('section div:nth-child('+$x+')').css('left', '150%');
            $('section div:nth-child('+$x+')').animate({ left: '50%' }, 500);
            currSlide = $('section div:nth-child('+$x+')').attr('id');
            $('section div:nth-child('+$x+') input').val(currSlide);
        } else {
            $('section div:nth-child('+$x+')').animate({ left: '-150%' }, 500);
            $x++;
            $('section div:nth-child('+$x+')').css('left', '150%');
            $('section div:nth-child('+$x+')').animate({ left: '50%' }, 500);
            currSlide = $('section div:nth-child('+$x+')').attr('id');
            $('section div:nth-child('+$x+') input').val(currSlide);
        };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your mouseenter and mouseleave lines with the below code. It works.

```
$('section div').mouseenter(function() {
   if(parseInt($(this).css('left')<0)) return;
   pause();
});
$('section div').mouseleave(function() { 
  if(parseInt($(this).css('left')<0)) return;
   $x = 2; start(); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ywr3ns6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#'+currSlide).mouseover(function() { pause(); });
$('#'+currSlide).mouseout(function() { $x = 2; start(); });
```